# Unexpected tidy eval behaviour in dplyr lag call

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

I have a function that takes a data frame and a couple of variables and I want it to produce a set of lagged variables using tidy evaluation principles. In it's simple form it looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
cor_lags <- function(df, var1, var2) {
  var1 <- enquo(var1)
  var2 <- enquo(var2)
  df %>% 
    select(!!var1, !!var2) %>% 
    mutate(lag1 = lag(!!var2, 1),
           lag2 = lag(!!var2, 2),
           lag3 = lag(!!var2, 3),
           lag4 = lag(!!var2, 4),
           lag5 = lag(!!var2, 5),
           lag6 = lag(!!var2, 6))
}
```

However, this produces `NA` values for all of the lagged variables.

```
cor_lags(dts_wide,"P26","P1")
# A tibble: 24 x 8
       P26     P1 lag1  lag2  lag3  lag4  lag5  lag6 
     <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1  84332.  2258. NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 2  63995.  2752. NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 3  86208. 10126. NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 4 103455.  3767. NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 5 160524. 12986. NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 6 306683.  3944. NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 7 599589.  3695. NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 8 642343.  6202. NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 9 482021.  8769. NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
10 220949.  5059. NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Is there a reason that the !! evaluators are not working within the `lag` call? They are clearly working in the `select` call.

The expected behaviour of the above call should work in practice like this code (which works):

```
# Expected
cor_lags <- function(df, var1, var2) {
  var1 <- enquo(var1)
  var2 <- enquo(var2)
  df %>% 
    select(!!var1, !!var2) %>% 
    mutate(lag1 = lag(P1, 1),
           lag2 = lag(P1, 2),
           lag3 = lag(P1, 3),
           lag4 = lag(P1, 4),
           lag5 = lag(P1, 5),
           lag6 = lag(P1, 6))
}
```

And which produces, as expected:

```
cor_lags(dts_wide,"P26","P1")
# A tibble: 24 x 8
       P26     P1   lag1   lag2   lag3   lag4   lag5   lag6
     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  84332.  2258.    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA 
 2  63995.  2752.  2258.    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA 
 3  86208. 10126.  2752.  2258.    NA     NA     NA     NA 
 4 103455.  3767. 10126.  2752.  2258.    NA     NA     NA 
 5 160524. 12986.  3767. 10126.  2752.  2258.    NA     NA 
 6 306683.  3944. 12986.  3767. 10126.  2752.  2258.    NA 
 7 599589.  3695.  3944. 12986.  3767. 10126.  2752.  2258.
 8 642343.  6202.  3695.  3944. 12986.  3767. 10126.  2752.
 9 482021.  8769.  6202.  3695.  3944. 12986.  3767. 10126.
10 220949.  5059.  8769.  6202.  3695.  3944. 12986.  3767.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing up quasi-quotation syntax. Either

- replace `enquo` with `sym` (or `rlang::sym`) to turn the string into a symbol,

  ```
  cor_lags <- function(df, var1, var2) {
    var1 <- sym(var1);                              # Turn string into symbol
    var2 <- sym(var2);                              # Turn string into symbol
    df %>%
      select(!!var1, !!var2) %>%
      mutate(lag1 = lag(!!var2, 1),
             lag2 = lag(!!var2, 2),
             lag3 = lag(!!var2, 3),
             lag4 = lag(!!var2, 4),
             lag5 = lag(!!var2, 5),
             lag6 = lag(!!var2, 6))
  }

  cor_lags(mtcars, "mpg", "disp") %>% head()        # var1, var2 as string
  #   mpg disp lag1 lag2 lag3 lag4 lag5 lag6
  #1 21.0  160   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
  #2 21.0  160  160   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
  #3 22.8  108  160  160   NA   NA   NA   NA
  #4 21.4  258  108  160  160   NA   NA   NA
  #5 18.7  360  258  108  160  160   NA   NA
  #6 18.1  225  360  258  108  160  160   NA
  ```
- or supply unquoted expressions for `var1` and `var2` and turn them into quosures with `enquo`

  ```
  cor_lags <- function(df, var1, var2) {
     var1 <- enquo(var1)                            # Turn expression into quosure
     var2 <- enquo(var2)                            # Turn expression into quosure
     df %>%
       select(!!var1, !!var2) %>%
       mutate(lag1 = lag(!!var2, 1),
              lag2 = lag(!!var2, 2),
              lag3 = lag(!!var2, 3),
              lag4 = lag(!!var2, 4),
              lag5 = lag(!!var2, 5),
              lag6 = lag(!!var2, 6))
  }
  cor_lags(mtcars, mpg, disp) %>% head()            # var1, var2 as expressions
  #   mpg disp lag1 lag2 lag3 lag4 lag5 lag6
  #1 21.0  160   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
  #2 21.0  160  160   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
  #3 22.8  108  160  160   NA   NA   NA   NA
  #4 21.4  258  108  160  160   NA   NA   NA
  #5 18.7  360  258  108  160  160   NA   NA
  #6 18.1  225  360  258  108  160  160   NA
  ```

Comment: Thanks, `rlang::sym` works exactly, but I'm left confused why enquo + !! works in the select call but not in the lag call here.

Answer (score 1):

We could create a function which can take both unquoted and quoted strings

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
cor_lags <- function(df, var1, var2) {


  var1 <- parse_expr(quo_name(enquo(var1)))                           
  var2 <- parse_expr(quo_name(enquo(var2)))   


  df %>%   
    select(!! var1, !! var2) %>%
    mutate(lag1 = lag(!!var2, 1),
           lag2 = lag(!!var2, 2),
           lag3 = lag(!!var2, 3),
           lag4 = lag(!!var2, 4),
           lag5 = lag(!!var2, 5),
           lag6 = lag(!!var2, 6))
}
```

-testing

```
cor_lags(mtcars, "mpg", "disp") %>% 
        head() 
#   mpg disp lag1 lag2 lag3 lag4 lag5 lag6
#1 21.0  160   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#2 21.0  160  160   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#3 22.8  108  160  160   NA   NA   NA   NA
#4 21.4  258  108  160  160   NA   NA   NA
#5 18.7  360  258  108  160  160   NA   NA
#6 18.1  225  360  258  108  160  160   NA

cor_lags(mtcars, mpg, disp) %>%
         head()    
#  mpg disp lag1 lag2 lag3 lag4 lag5 lag6
#1 21.0  160   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#2 21.0  160  160   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#3 22.8  108  160  160   NA   NA   NA   NA
#4 21.4  258  108  160  160   NA   NA   NA
#5 18.7  360  258  108  160  160   NA   NA
#6 18.1  225  360  258  108  160  160   NA
```